# bsort example from programming pearls

Tags: c++, sorting, programming-pearls

In Programming Pearls there is an algorithm that sorts varying length arrays but sorts in time proportional to the sum of their length. For example, if we have a record array `x[0...n-1]`, and each record has an integer length and a pointer to array `bit[0...length-1]`.

The code is implemented this way:

```
void bsort(l, u, depth){
    if (l >= u)
        return ;
    for (i = l; i <= u; i++){
        if (x[i].length < depth)
            swap(i, l++);
    }
    m = l;
    for (int i = l; i < u; i++){
        if (x[i].bit[depth] == 0)
            swap(i, m++);
    }
    bsort(l, m - 1, depth + 1);
    bsort(m, u, depth + 1);
}
```

My question is that, given the record:

```
x[6] = {"car", "bus", "snow", "earth", "dog", "mouse"}
```

I know how to get the string length, but what about with a bit array? How could I make a bit array suitable for this string array? And even `x[i].bit[depth]` how can I  implement this?

Comment: I tried to clean this up but your question still isn't very clear. Is it basically that you're thinking of sorting a `char[]` and you want to know if you can sort a bit array? I think it depends on how your bit array is implemented.

Comment: i want to say that,it is not clear to me too how can i implement bit sort with string's record,can't understand it

Answer (score 1):

Arrays of chars (or any other type, for that matter) are also arrays of bits - chars are made of bits, after all. So you don't have to create a separate array, you just have to find a way to access a given bit in the array. For that, you'll have to use some bit manipulations. You can find a few examples of how this could be done here: [Any smarter way to extract from array of bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160720/any-smarter-way-to-extract-from-array-of-bits).

Basically, you first have to figure out the byte the required bit is at, and then get that specific bit's value. Something along:

```
char* array = "the array";
int required_bit = 13;
int bit = required_bit & 0x7;  // get the bit's offset in its byte
int byte = required_bit >> 3;  // get the bit's byte
int val = (array[byte] >> bit) & 0x1; // check if the bit is 1
```

Now wrap this in a function (possibly with additional bound checks, to make sure the given `required_bit` is not outside of the array), and use with `x[i]`.

Comment: it is  very  great answer @eran,just one question  suppose instead of  string array,we have integer array,then x[i].length it is number of digit for represent this number yes?and additionaly x[i].bit[depth] it is  bit in number  at position  depth yes?

Comment: You can't use `x[i].length` to get an array's length, this is not Java... With strings, you can use `strlen`. With ints, you have to pass the size along with the array. Also, you don't have a `bit[depth]` part - you work on `x[i]`. Lastly, if you have an int array, you'll have to make some changes - ints aren't 1 byte, so `array[byte]` won't access the `byte` byte, but the `byte` int. easiest would be to cast the `int*` into a `char*`.

Comment: sorry @eran,but i am confused already,in my example how  my code would be written?i have string array  shown in example,please tell me  how would my code looks?

Comment: You should first, say, create a `int get_bit(char* array, int bitpos)` function. Then, call it as `int bit_val = get_bit(x[i], depth)` (assuming `depth` is the bit whose value you're interested in). This will get you the `depth` bit in the `x[i]` array.

Comment: but  x[i] is array of characters not one character yes?or it does not matter

Comment: It should be an array of chars. Look at the function's definition and the example code.

Comment: ok @eran  thank you for help,i will try to understand it,just only one confusion is that,even i will return my example,we  should take  x array,which contains   strings and these strings itself are  array of chars,so  what a hell code from programming pearls